# What is The Recommended Architecture for ASP.NET Web Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, architecture

In the first comment (by J.W.) to this question:

[Using ObjectDataSource and DataObjectTypeName, How Do You Handle Delete Methods With Just An Id Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913571/using-objectdatasource-and-dataobjecttypename-how-do-you-handle-delete-methods-w),

it is said that using ObjectDataSource is a bad design.

What is considered good design for well-architected ASP.NET applications?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ultimate resource for asp.net application architecture. [Imaar](http://imar.spaanjaars.com) has written few books on ASP.NET and he's published 2 series of articles on how you should architect your asp.net apps. [One series](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=416) is for ASP.NET 2.0 and [another series](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476) is for ASP.NET 3.5

**Link Txt 1:** http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=416

**Link Txt 1:** http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476

And believe me ObjectDataSource rocks. There's nothing wrong in using, if you can play with it well.

Thanks.